# Meaning of Problem in Evaluation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In Algebra, a good rule-of-thumb I saw was *If solving an equation leads to a contradiction, there is no solution*. And this makes sense to me, particularly in the following case:

$x-1 = x +1 \Rightarrow -1 = 1$

We are being asked to find a number whose **predecessor** is the same as its **successor**. That would require 1 and -1 to have the same effect on $x$. Impossible! But I was shown another case of *no solution* -- an equation that seemed to have a valid solution up until checking:

$\frac{2}{x+2} + \frac{x}{x-2} = \frac{x^2+4}{x^2-4} \Rightarrow 2(x-2)+x(x+2) = x^2+4$

Solving this for $x$, we can get an answer of $x=2$. But we see in the original equation, $x\neq2$ because of division by zero. So there is *no solution*.

My question is: What does it mean (geometrically / algebraically / logically) if solving an equation does not halt in a contradiction, but causes a contradiction on evaluation?

Comment: The way I understand this is:
You multiplied by $(x+2)(x-2)$, which when $x = \pm2$ equals zero, so you basically multiplied the equation by 0, which introduced new solutions to the equation.


Just like when you take the equation:
$x = 5$
and multiply it by 0, you get:
$0 = 0$
which means the equation is true for all x, which obviously it isn't.

Here's a wikipedia article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{x+2} + \frac{x}{x-2} = \frac{x^2+4}{x^2-4} \quad \overset{\large x\neq \pm 2}{\Longrightarrow} \quad2(x-2)+x(x+2) = x^2+4$$

In moving from the left-hand side to the right-hand side of the "implication" above, you implicitly multiplied both terms on the left, along with the right hand side of the equation to the left, by $$x^2 - 4 = (x + 2)(x - 2)$$. If we do not qualify that "operation" by the provision $x\neq \pm 2$, we are allowing for the possibility of multiplication by zero. Any equation, when multiplied by zero, may change in ways that [introduce extraneous solutions which aren't actually solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) to the original equation. Without omitting $x = \pm 2$ (to disallow multiplication by zero), we dilute the original equation and  information about the **original equation** is lost.

So the *apparent* solution of $x = 2$ was introduced by manipulations on the original equation, and in particular, by forgetting the provision I've made explicit above the "implication" connective above. I wouldn't necessarily say that we arrived at a contradiction, but rather found information that turned out to be information (an *apparent solution*) that doesn't apply to the original equation which has no solution.

Comment: Including where the expression turns to zero above the arrow makes a lot of sense to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally it means that the original function is not defined at the value you arrived at. Usually there is an asymptote, but there can also just be a discontinuity.

Comment: It's not a function being evaluated, but an equation, and an equation which has no solution: no value x at which equality holds.

Comment: @amWhy I know it is not a function, but I think making this problem as finding the zeroes $f(x)=\frac{2}{x+2} + \frac{x}{x-2} - \frac{x^2+4}{x^2-4} $ can give the OP the geometric representation he/she was probably looking for.